# How to resolve 500 status when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activerecord, rubygems

```
2023-02-15T20:31:47.060556+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-02-15T20:31:47.060491 #2]  INFO -- : [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 66.249.64.84 at 2023-02-15 20:31:47 +0000
2023-02-15T20:31:47.061344+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-02-15T20:31:47.061287 #2]  INFO -- : [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2023-02-15T20:31:47.062452+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2023-02-15T20:31:47.062413 #2] DEBUG -- : [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f]    (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
2023-02-15T20:31:47.062848+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-02-15T20:31:47.062814 #2]  INFO -- : [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 527)
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063561+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-02-15T20:31:47.063527 #2] FATAL -- : [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f]
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063561+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063562+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f]
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063562+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:346:in `table_structure'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063563+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:116:in `columns'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063563+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:112:in `block in columns'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063563+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:111:in `fetch'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063564+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:111:in `columns'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063564+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:120:in `block in columns_hash'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063564+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:119:in `fetch'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063564+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:119:in `columns_hash'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063565+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:553:in `load_schema!'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063566+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/attributes.rb:250:in `load_schema!'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063566+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:539:in `block in load_schema'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063566+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:536:in `synchronize'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063567+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:536:in `load_schema'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063567+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:402:in `attribute_types'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063567+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:187:in `_has_attribute?'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063567+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:57:in `new'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063567+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] devise (4.8.1) lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:22:in `new_with_session'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063568+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] devise (4.8.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:100:in `build_resource'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063568+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] devise (4.8.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:10:in `new'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063568+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063568+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063568+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063569+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063569+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063569+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actiontext (6.1.7.2) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063570+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actiontext (6.1.7.2) lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063570+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063570+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063570+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063570+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063573+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063573+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063573+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063574+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063574+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063574+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063574+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063575+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activerecord (6.1.7.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063575+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063575+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionview (6.1.7.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063575+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063576+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063576+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063576+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063576+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063576+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063577+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063577+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063577+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063577+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063577+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/deflater.rb:44:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063578+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063578+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063578+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063578+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:19:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063579+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063580+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:697:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063580+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063580+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063580+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063583+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063583+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063583+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063583+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] railties (6.1.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] railties (6.1.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] railties (6.1.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063584+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] activesupport (6.1.7.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063585+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:77:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] actionpack (6.1.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:142:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] railties (6.1.7.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] puma (4.3.12) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] puma (4.3.12) lib/puma/server.rb:727:in `handle_request'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] puma (4.3.12) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] puma (4.3.12) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
2023-02-15T20:31:47.063586+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8806da7-4389-4a8f-b176-19ed6c60103f] puma (4.3.12) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Ruby app was previously on Heroku-18 stack and deprecated a few months ago. I upgraded to Heroku-22 stack on yesterday and have not had any success being able to login or sign up to the app. The app successfully deploys to Heroku and I can access the homepage but when I navigate to enter information to be stored in the database I receive the, "We're sorry, but something went wrong", error.

When I run the Heroku logs command I receive the above print out for the logs. I've updated the ruby gem version and rails version on the app as well.

I'm not sure how to fix/correct the issues?

Comment: Is your Database of type SQL3 ? Also it says it can't find table Users. If this is an existing app I guess the database exists and all migrations have been done. Is your database plan well linked to your app ?

Comment: @Maxence The adapter in my database.yml file lists SQL3 for production. In my gemfile I have gem 'pg' listed for production. What do you mean by database plan?

Comment: Actually just checked and the only database plan at Heroku seems Heroku PG. Not even sure they support MySQL. Though SQLITE3 as the error mentions in your logs is a self contained database. You are the only one who can know if your DB should be PG or Sqlite. What do you use in development ?

Comment: @Maxence In development I use sqlite3. I used the 'pg' gem on the heroku-18 stack and had no issues. Are you saying it's a database compatibility/adapter issue from the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your application is configured to use `SQLite` as database adapter and that there was no database found. Using SQLite will certainly not work because of Heroku's [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku#ephemeral-disk) (unless it is a read-only database).

Instead, the most common and best documented option is to use a [Heroku PostgreSQL database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) that can be added as an add-on. Alternatively, there are other many other [database add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#data-stores) available, or you could configure a database running on your own server or, for example, on an AWS RDS database.

Assuming you want to use the Heroku Postgres option, you simply need to add the add-on to your application. And by doing so, Heroku will configure a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable and keep it updated for you.

Within your application, you will need to do three things:

1. Add the `pg` gem to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle update`. You might only want to add this gem to the production group in the `Gemfile`. But I suggest using Postgres in development and test environment too, to avoid running into issues because SQLite and Postgres behave differently in some cases.
2. Then update your `config/database.yml` to use the `DATABASE_URL` set by Heroku to configure the database connection. That will likely have to look like this:

   ```
   production:
     adapter: postgresql
     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
   ```

   Commit and push those changes to Heroku.
3. After deploying those changes, you will need to run migrations on Heroku by running `heroku run rails db:migrate` to start with an empty database, or you might want to import data from another database.

I suggest reading about [Ruby Database Provisioning](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-database-provisioning) and [Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) in the Heroku Dev Center.

Comment: Thank you. Adding the Heroku PostgresSQL database did the trick. There was an incompatibility between the ruby version set and the version of rails used for the project that caused conflicts with the `pg` gem.